# Voltage calculation and reference voltage in simple linear circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

[image]

> For the diagram above, the following voltages are specified:
>
> $V_A = 4V$ 
>   $V_D = 2V$ 
>   $V_a = 0V$
>
> Here, $V_{ab}$ indicates the voltage referenced from node b to node a. In other words, imagine $V_{ab}$ being identified in the diagram as having a "-" at node b and a "+" at node a. The other voltages are specified using the labeled references. $V_a$ is the value of the voltage potential at node a.
>
> **Question 1:**
>   Find the value of $V_B$ in volts and enter it in the box below.
>
> **Question 2:**
>   Find $V_{ab}$
>
> **Question 3**
>   For the same circuit above, find $V_C$ and enter it into the space below without units. ($V_C$ is the voltage across the top element, not the voltage at the point c in the circuit.)

I'm teaching myself linear circuits and came across these problems.  I got Question 1 correct but cannot understand questions 2,3.

Question 1:  Since $V_B$ is in parallel with $V_A$, I thought $V_B = 4V$.  Is this the correct thinking?

Question 2:  Since $V_a = 0V$, the voltage at this node is 0V.  We also determined the voltage across $V_B$, so I thought this solution would also be 4V-- but this is incorrect.  Can someone please explain why?

Question 3:  Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1: Since VB is in parallel with VA, I thought VB=4V. Is this the correct thinking?

Yes.

> Question 2: Since Va=0V, the voltage at this node is 0V. We also determined the voltage across VB, so I thought this solution would also be 4V

Remember your sign convention. $V_{ab}$ is defined with an opposite sign convention from $V_A$ or $V_B$.

> Question 3: Not sure.

You need to use Kirchoff's Voltage Law (KVL) here.